# Why PIL's image.show() is not working on google collab notebook

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, jupyter, show

I am using PIL library to display an image in google collab notebook. But it is not working. Can someone tell me the reason and the way to display the image. I am putting my code below.

```
from PIL import Image
Im=Image.open('image_name.png')
Im.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem arises in case of Jupyter Notebooks. Using show() does not display the image. So discard calling show() like in the code below. This will display the image in the output of the cell.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("lists.jpg")
im
```